# QuickSort Python Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm new to algorithms and I wrote a Quick Sort algorithm for homework, but there is something not going right. I searched for hours, where ever possible, I couldn't find why it doesn't work !

---

```
def quick_sort(array):

    if len(array) > 1:

       pivot = array[0]
       index_lower = 1

       for index in range(len(array)):

            if array[index] < pivot:
                array[index_lower], array[index] = array[index], array[index_lower]
                index_lower += 1

       array[index_lower-1], array[0] = array[0], array[index_lower-1]

       left_array = array[:index_lower]
       pivot = array[index_lower:index_lower+1]
       right_array = array[index_lower+1:]

       quick_sort(left_array)
       quick_sort(right_array)

       sorted_array = left_array + pivot + right_array

       return sorted_array

array = [78, 45, 2, 111, 49, 44, 98, 777, 345, 6548, 4954654, 123, 1, 3, 5]

x = quick_sort(array)
print x
```

---

The output I get on this code is :

[3, 2, 1, 5, 44, 45, 49, 78, 345, 777, 123, 111, 98, 6548, 4954654]

Comment: please indent your code example the same way as your code..

Comment: I did, thank you for telling me.

Comment: This should be easier to follow http://pastebin.com/DWHK9ddW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two styles of implementing a recursive function:

1. recursive function receives an array and returns a new array that is sorted
2. recursive function receives an array and modifies the same array, and returns nothing.

1) is broken since you are not returning anything when `len(array) <= 1`, and you do nothing with the result of `quicksort(left_array)`.

2) is broken since you are only doing the initial sorting on the input `array` itself, while the result of `left_array + pivot + right_array` is not applied **to the original array**.

The easiest would probably be to write your function using the first style only, since the second style requires a good knowledge of how python variables are modified in-place and passed around between functions.

Answer (score 0):

You return the sorted array, but never use the return value:

```
   left_array = quick_sort(left_array)
   right_array = quick_sort(right_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here:

```
   quick_sort(left_array)
   quick_sort(right_array)
```

I see the recursive Call, but you discard the result.

It should be

```
   left_array = quick_sort(left_array)
   richt_array = quick_sort(right_array)
```

You also forgot the return for the case that the array length is 1.